# how to handle a size=0 response in MYSQL & Mule

Tags: mysql, mule, esb

I'm using mulesoft esb 3.7 with MySQL. If I run a query with no resultset I notice the payload has a value of size=0...How do I evaluate that in a choice router? Is it `#[flowVars.size==0]` or `#[payload==null]`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@sam, use a debugger and check whether the type of the resultset is a collection or not, say if it is a list then use #[payload.size()==0] if not then you'll see that the payload is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

database component always returns a List object so no need of collection check.
you can check directly `#[payload.size()==0]`

Answer (score 0):

In case of restful exception handling, use the validation component `is-not-empty`. If it's empty, the `NotFoundException` will be thrown. Easy to handle it in the exception strategie.

```
<validation:is-not-empty value="#[payload]" exceptionClass="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.NotFoundException" />
```